# Walsh-Lebesgue type theorem in $\Bbb R^{2m}$ for $m>1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory, clifford-algebras

**Is someone aware of any analogue of the Walsh-Lebesgue theorem in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ for $m>1$ and dealing with polyharmonic polynomials?**

In this post,  $\phi$ is said to be polyharmonic in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ if it solves $\Delta^m \phi=0$. The case $m=1$ is the "classical" harmonic case: it contains the Weistrass theorem (the one dealing with the uniform approximation of $2\pi$-periodic continuous functions by trigonometric polynomials) and it can be seen as a corollary of Runge's theorem in complex analysis.

More specifically, a more modest version of my question could be:

*if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ with smooth boundary and $\psi$ is some given polyharmonic function in $\Omega$ (say continuous in $\bar{\Omega}$), letting $Z_\psi$ be its zero set in $\bar{\Omega}$, is-it true that the set of (the restrictions of) the polyharmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ (or in $\bar{\Omega}$ in some sense) are dense in $C^0(Z_\psi)$ for the uniform norm?*

Unless I am wrong, using the maximum principle, the case $m=1$ of this more specific question is a corollary of the aforementioned classical Walsh-Lebesgue theorem.

Many thanks in advance for any clue about this!

NB: I found some references for analogs of Runge's theorem in higer dimensions (dealing with Cliffordian functions, but, unless I missed it, it does not clearly solve the present question).